# Is there a way to programatically create a gradient on an image in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradient

On Android.

I am looking for a way to create a background drawable which will give the image a transparent gradient.

Aiming to have the top of the image slightly less opaque than the original image and fade down to a completely transparent image.

Would like to do this as part of a drawable so I can apply to any of the items within a RecyclerView during run time.

Be grateful for any help if anyone has any idea.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Example - Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image"/>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#00efefef"
                android:endColor="#ffefefef"
                android:angle="270"
                android:type="linear"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Will test this and get back to you, thanks @snorlax.

Comment: This is great thank you. Just so I can clarify how I have used it. I have a card view in my XML, which I have applied this to the 'foreground' and this has worked perfectly. Thank you @snorlax